# Scalar Product Notation

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a problem in my textbook, the context is not very important but it does have the equation

$[c \cdot (b \cdot \nabla)-b \cdot (c \cdot \nabla)]a = (\nabla \times a)\cdot(b \times c)$

a, b, c are all vector fields. My question is whether or not the LHS of the equation is proper notation or not. Obviously the answer is a scalar so can I expand the LHS and write

$(c \cdot a)(b \cdot \nabla)-(b \cdot a)(c \cdot \nabla) = (\nabla \times a)\cdot(b \times c)$

Why/why not?

Comment: Sure, there isn't any reason why you can't write like that

Answer (score 1):

The identity should be $$(\underline{\nabla}\times\underline{a})\cdot(\underline{b}\times\underline{c})=(\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{b})(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{c})-(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{b})(\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{c})$$

Comment: Isn't the $[c \cdot (b \cdot \nabla)-b \cdot (c \cdot \nabla)]$ a vector operator?

Comment: @Botond using the dots in this way makes no sense since dot product is an operation between two vectors not a vector and a scalar

Comment: I didn't wanted to ask if the dot between the $c$ and $(b \cdot \nabla)$ is correct, but if $[c(b \cdot \nabla)-b(c \cdot \nabla)]$ is a vector operator.

Comment: @Botond yes when written like that it would be, surely?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question as well.